# Not able to resolve the Promise on client side JS form express res.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am not able to debug or figure out why my request is logging raw HTTP response as shown in the image on the browser console once the `expressjs` server returns the JSON response. Let me kick in all relevant code and we can talk then
[image]

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Infinite Scroll</title>
    <script src="./infiniteScroll.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="testimonial-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**infiniteScroll.js**

```
async function fetchAndAppendTestimonials(limit = 5, after = 0) {
  const testimonials = await fetch('/testimonials');
  console.log(testimonials);
}
fetchAndAppendTestimonials(5, 0);
```

I starting adding `server.js` incrementally so that I can bypass CORS to call the external API - 'https://api.frontendexpert.io/api/fe/testimonials';

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 80;
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('public'));
const API_BASE_URL = 'https://api.frontendexpert.io/api/fe/testimonials';

async function fetchTestimonials(limit = 5, after = 0) {
  const testimonialUrl = new URL(API_BASE_URL);
  testimonialUrl.searchParams.set('limit', limit);
  //   testimonialUrl.searchParams.set('after', after);
  try {
    const testimonials = await axios.get(testimonialUrl);
    // console.log(testimonials);
    return testimonials.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  }
}
app.get('/testimonials', async function (req, res) {
  const testimonials = await fetchTestimonials(5, 10);
  console.log(testimonials);
  res.json(testimonials);
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server is running on port', port);
});
```

So on the client console, I am getting a log of raw HTTP response and not the actual JSON. On the express server function, I am getting the exact response. Don't know what is missing.

Comment: "I am not able to debug" - why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>  const testimonials = await fetch('/testimonials');
>  console.log(testimonials);
> ```

> I am not able to debug or figure out why my request is logging raw HTTP response

Well, the first step would be to [read the documentation for `fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch):

> Return value: A Promise that resolves to a Response object.

`fetch` returns a [`Response` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) wrapped in a promise.

You're unwrapping it with `await` and then logging the `Response` object.

It has various methods on it (such as [the `json` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) to wait for the body data to arrive and process it in various ways.

For example, if you want to get the JSON representation of the response body, you can do the following:

```js
const response = await fetch('/testimonials');
const testimonials = await response.json()
console.log(testimonials);
```

Comment: Ah! Missed the await on response.json(), tried that and I was wondering.